# Add elements from vectors using different indices

Tags: r

Given two vectors x,y:

```
x <- c( 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.01, 5.12, 9.59)
y <- c( 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.78, 0.45, 6.78)
```

In R notation using vector operation (not for loop), how to take y divided by the sum of some subset of x where I specify the indices:

```
y / ( x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] )
```

This would be the same as manually taking y / 10.01 and returning a vector length y. I've tried using seq() and subsetting but don't know.

Comment: yes, sorry i thought i tried that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using `sum` and `head` functions:

```
> y/sum(head(x, 4))
[1] 0.00999001 0.01998002 0.02997003 0.07792208 0.04495504 0.67732268
```

you can also use `seq`

```
y/sum(x[seq(4)])
```

which is the same as @Rcoster's comment `y / sum(x[1:4])`